# What's wrong with this try catch?

Tags: php

```
function rseo_get_seo($check, $post){
//code breaks somewhere in here. or in the rseo_doTheParse function.
switch ($check)
{
case "h1": return rseo_doTheParse('h1', $post);
case "h2": return rseo_doTheParse('h2', $post);
case "h3": return rseo_doTheParse('h3', $post);
case "img-alt": return rseo_doTheParse('img-alt', $post);
}
}

function rseo_doTheParse($heading, $post){
    try { //I get a FATAL error here. unexpected '{'
        $content = $post->post_content;

        if ($content == "") return false;

        $keyword = trim(strtolower(rseo_getKeyword($post)));
        @$dom = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom->loadHTML(strtolower($post->post_content));
        $xPath = new DOMXPath(@$dom);

        switch ($heading)
        {
            case "img-alt": return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(//img[contains(@alt, "'.$keyword.'")])');
            default: return $xPath->evaluate('boolean(/html/body//'.$heading.'[contains(.,"'.$keyword.'")])');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Exception caught: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works [here](http://ideone.com/PjAqO)

Comment: You aren't using PHP 4 by chance?

Comment: This is weird. Are you sure that you also checked the code above this function? It maybe could happend because of an unclosed function, if-clause etc. - I'm not sure but this code piece looks correct. EDIT: marcog's answer also underlines that it has nothing to do with this code piece. So you should investigate somewhere else.

Comment: @nikic: Didn't see your comment before I posted my answer, oops.

Comment: @nikic, its a WordPress site on HostGator. How can I tell?

Comment: @Scott B: Not sure how HostGator tells you but you can run a PHP script with `phpinfo()` and see.

Comment: Yep, Its php4 > /usr/local/php4/lib/php.ini

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you're on PHP 4, which doesn't support exception handling. So it thinks `try` is some kind of constant, but doesn't expect a `{` to be there.

You should have gotten a **parse** error, not a **fatal** error.

Comment: +1 That would result in the exact error at the exact spot that the OP describes.

Comment: Except OP should have said `parse`. Fatal is a run-time error.

Comment: This should be the correct solution. Normally more errors appear if there wasn't an old function/clause closed.

Comment: Does WordPress have a utility function to determine what version of PHP its working with on the server?

Comment: @Scott B: I don't think so. You should be able to just run a PHP script that contains a `phpinfo()` call to see the version.

Answer (score 1):

That code is 100% valid. Perhaps the error is elsewhere. On a side note, DOM functions don't throw exceptions--you might want to look into [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)and set it up to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted the code in a new file and ran it: no error. The problem might be above your code?

Answer (score 0):

Line 14 after the switch block.  Remove the second } just before the catch block

Comment: 1 } is for the switch, the second is the end of the try. So it should be good, right?